# How to give specific port to Apache in Ubuntu 12.04 and port for mysql

Tags: 12.04, apache2, xampp

I am using xampp Apache server but it works locally i want to access it from public ip and i know the whole process but i am stuck how to change the port for Apache server because i dont want to access it with port 80 but is it possible that apache will run on other port please help and also how to change the port of mysql

Comment: Please, read the question marked as duplicated of this. It clearly says how to change the default port. For Mysql, you should ask another question.

Comment: if i have problem thats why i am asking its not clear you are insisting to me to remove this question why

Comment: I haven't said that you should remove your question. I'm saying that if you have another question, which is totally unrelated to Apache (even through you may say that they are) you should ask another question.

Comment: @AitazazKhan we limit each post to one question. You have two different questions, Apache and MySQL. The Apache issue is solved (look at the duplicate question). For your MySQL question, please [ask another question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask), just like you asked the Apache question. This is because these are two different problems, with two different solutions. Thanks.

Comment: if it is getting solved here and new newcomers are taking part with new idea what is the problem with you people although knowledge is a ocean don't underestimate any one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple , you can do it with listen  command.
I mean open your terminal with CTRL+ALT+T then type as

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Then make the line as

```
Listen 8000
```

save & close.
restart your apache server.
now your apache will start listening to port number 8000.

Comment: why don't put that in /etc/apache2/ports.conf ?

Comment: @Private my friend , I am saying that only right ? I am familiar with this type of modification.

Comment: i know. i am new, thats why i ask. if it's the same then it's fine. thx

Comment: Using above configuration, apache will listen on 80 and 8000 ports. In order to set 8000 as default port, change it in  /etc/apache2/ports.conf file.